# How do we host multiple HTML files in a single S3 bucket to get separate URLs for each file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I'm new to using AWS S3. I need to host my privacy policy HTML page and T&C HTML page in the S3 bucket as static web pages. I need separate URLs for those two files but I can not create separate S3 buckets for each file. So is there any way to full fill my requirement?

I need this kind of URLs after hosting the pages in the S3 bucket

```
http://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/privacypolicy.html
http://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com/termsandcondition.html
```

*also, I can not create an index file for these HTML pages and after that link these HTML pages to that index file, because I need these URLs to link my mobile app. once the user clicks one of the links, the user should go to that page so that's why I need separate URL for these files.*

Comment: The S3 links work exactly as you posted. What is the problem with those links?

Comment: As @Marcin said, this is how s3 website hosting works, for your clarity added the exact steps i followed, try it once. if it helped you an acceptance/upvote would help others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You dont have to create separate bucket

Just create 2 HTML files for example site1.html and site2.html.
Here are the steps to follow

- upload site1.html and site2.html
- enable website hosting and enter site1.html instead of index.html
- turn off block public access setting
- add bucket policy to access bucket publicly https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html
- access website using website hosting URL link, this will lead to site1.html, if you want to access site2.html just append site2.html to root address

for example
here is my link for site1.html
http://stack-trial.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/

**Note**: you can also access the site1.html using this http://stack-trial.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/site1.html.

for site2.html
http://stack-trial.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/site2.html

Comment: Update I have deleted my bucket but this is the general idea to have multiple pages